# Force scrolling/bouncing edge effect HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I would like to allow my HorizontalScrollView to be scrollable even if it doesn't have enough items. If I have say like 5 images on my ScrollView it scrolls. But when I only have 3 it doesn't. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: ummm not really clear about your problem. If there aren't enough items in your scrollview it will not scroll. Kinda makes sense. Do you just want to give it an effect that the list is scrollable even when there are fewer items?

Comment: yup. just like a scrollview in iOS.

Comment: I looked for a way to do it by default but as per my knowledge this is not possible. You could always think of a hack like adding an empty view at the end but thats really dirty. Something clean would be to extend HorizontalScrollView and put in the effect u desire. Will update if i see something interesting.

Comment: hmm... but is it not really possible for the horizontalscrollview to have a 'bounce' effect?

Comment: just an FYI, the gallery has the kind of effect u want. I am not sure if u can adapt it to ure requirement. But u could give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

By my understand, would you like alway enable overScrollMode, in this case, just add `android:overScrollMode="always"` in your define scrollview xml:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:overScrollMode="always">
```

Comment: Gives the default Android rubber band effect. I think @SleepNot wants something similar to the iOS behavior